# Regex to check if string starts with a letter and doesnt contain substring

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex that checks if a string:

- starts with a letter and
- doesn't contain certain substrings.

Here is what i have:

```
^(?!class|icon|style|color).*$
```

Basically my strings shouldn't have a substring of class, icon, style or color.

Now, how can I make it check if it starts with a letter?

Expected behavior:

- `class` - should fail
- `class=something` - should fail
- `:somethingelse` - should fail
- `somethingelse` - should pass

Here is my attempt to check starting character:

```
^[a-z](?!class|icon|style|color).*$
```

But it just doesnt work. This regex causes only the first condition to be checked (starts with letter) and completely disregards checking for 'forbidden' words (class, icon, etc).

Thank you!

Comment: @RyanM Oh yes! Totally forgot about that. I have updated my question with an example now. Thank you!

Comment: What about the string, "It was an iconic classroom"? You speak of substrings and forbidden words. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, but the first two components of your regex are swapped.  You need to be checking the negative lookahead at the very start of the string, not after the first character.  With those swapped, you get:

```regex
^(?!class|icon|style|color)[a-z].*$
```

which passes all your tests.

Note that this does not check that it doesn't contain the substring *anywhere*, just that it doesn't *start* with those substrings. For that, you could add a `.*` to the start of the lookahead, and enclose the rest of the lookahead in a group:

```regex
^(?!.*(?:class|icon|style|color))[a-z].*$
```

It also only finds lowercase letters at the start (an assumption based on your examples and your initial starting point).  If you're looking for any ASCII letter, replace `[a-z]` with `[a-zA-Z]`.  For any letter of any type (there are [lots](https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/unicode.html)), use [ikegami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62337203/208273).

Live demo: https://regex101.com/r/ZA3uQk/1/tests

Comment: Great!! Yes, starting with those substrings would work just fine. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

What you have (`^(?!class|icon|style|color).*$`) doesn't even do what you said it does. It fails if string *starts* with `class`, but not if it merely *contains* `class`.

Normally, you'd do two matches for readability.

```perl
/^\pL/ && !/class|icon|style|color/   # \pL is short for \p{Letter}
```

But you can use lookaheads to "and" multiple matches together.

```perl
/
    ^
    (?= \pL )
    (?! .* (?:class|icon|style|color) )
/sx
```

Since all the lookaheads start matching at the same location, the lookaheads can be reordered, and the last lookahead can be turned into a regular match if it's a positive lookahead. This allows us to simplify the above into the following:

```perl
/
    ^
    (?! .* (?:class|icon|style|color) )
    \pL
/sx
```

Ok, that's technically a regex match operator. It is equivalent to the following regex pattern:

```
(?sx:
    ^
    (?! .* (?:class|icon|style|color) )
    \pL
)
```

You didn't specify which regex language you are using. The above uses Perl.